# Execute stored procedure if row was inserted within last minute

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a trigger that fires a stored procedure when data is inserted. The procedure works fine but I need to set a condition - I have a column `ACCESSEDTIME` that is in the format of 'time'. My stored procedure should execute if `ACCESSEDTIME` is less than 1 minute and the column 'TYPE' is equal to 'Exception'. I'm not getting an error, but the procedure is not executing when using the following code before BEGIN.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM LOGS 
    WHERE Logs.TYPE = 'Exception' 
      AND CONVERT(datetime, ACCESSEDTIME) > DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE())) > 0
BEGIN
    -- my stored procedure
END
```

Comment: why is it `time` not `datetime`? `CONVERT(datetime, ACCESSEDTIME)` will be in 1900. much simpler to just store the datetime last accessed and no need for special logic to handle new day

Comment: @MartinSmith I took your advice and changed the time column to datetime and the procedure is working fine now without the need to convert the time column. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the ACCESSEDTIME column in the table to a datetime format instead of a time format. Then, there is no need to do conversion in the procedure on the column -  'ACCESSEDTIME' as in this example.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM LOGS 
    WHERE Logs.TYPE = 'Exception' 
    AND ACCESSEDTIME > DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE())) > 0
BEGIN
    -- my stored procedure
END
```